# Eclipse Installation Failed Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am going to learn Java. And I have downloaded Eclipse IDE and also installed jdk and jre from Oracle website and define them in Windows Variables but Whenever I try to install Eclipse, I get this error message:

```
    [2017-09-15 12:55:10] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_144-b01
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.oxygen
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.8.0.v20170408-0745, build=3059, branch=2161405b80cf99ed791602ba56cdf44084f5ca43
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.8.0.v20170531-0903, build=3059, branch=2161405b80cf99ed791602ba56cdf44084f5ca43
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.8.0.v20170318-0419, build=3059, branch=2161405b80cf99ed791602ba56cdf44084f5ca43
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Oxygen))
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Offline = false
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Mirrors = true
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Resolving 24 requirements from 3 repositories to G:\java-oxygen2\eclipse
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement epp.package.java [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201706281000
[2017-09-15 12:55:10] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2017-09-15 12:55:11] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/content.xml.
java.net.SocketException: SOCKS : authentication failed
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:473)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

[2017-09-15 12:55:11]
```

So if you know how can I fix, let me know, thanks.

Comment: It seems that the process is not able to access this resource: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/content.xml. Indeed, if you try to open it with a browser it gives a 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

If updating the Eclipse Installer does not fix your problem, **[download an Eclipse package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)** instead (only when installing multiple packages Eclipse Installer has the advantage that less disk space is used.).